# Magento2 theme layout files suddenly stopped working

Tags: magento, magento2

I am brand new to Magento, and am using Magento 2. I have a custom theme that has been working just fine. Suddenly, the files in my custom theme's `Magento_Theme/layout` folder seem to not be loading. In my layout folder I have `default_head_blocks.xml` and `default.xml`. BOTH files suddenly stopped working.

Here is my `default_head_blocks.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />​
    <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    <script src="js/site.js"></script>
 </head>
</page>
```

And my `default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="absolute_footer" template="html/absolute_footer.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="store.settings.currency" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="store_switcher" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
    <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    <move element="logo" destination="navigation.sections"/>
    <move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer"/>
    <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header.container"/>
    <move element="top.links" destination="footer"/>
 </body>
</page>
```

As I stated the files were working perfectly fine at one point.

The files in my `Magento_Theme/templates/html` folder load just fine.  Seems to only be the files in my layout folder.

Any ideas why this would be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Try to delete all folders in var/ and pub/static/ and then re-run the command of deploy, flush and reindex.

Comment: Could you specify how `BOTH files suddenly stopped working`. Do you receive any type of error? How did you find out they "stopped working"? We need some more info to help you.

Comment: Does any error coming on screen? Consol or Log files?

Comment: Facing same problem. @mmshr found any solution? Also if any one has solution then please share with us.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to website database, open theme table and chagne type = 0 for your current theme. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, instances like this would require you to do the following.

**Clean Cache:**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Flush Cache:**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**(optional)** if clearing cache doesn't seem to show any changes, you might need to do a static deploy.

**Static Deploy:** Note: this will take a bit of time depending on your system.

```
php ./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme <your theme example myTheme/Default>
```

After these processes you can try and reload the page again.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `<script>` in a wrong way inside inside the file default_head_blocks.xml.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
   <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />​
   <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
   <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
   <script src="js/site.js"/>
  </head>
 </page>
```

**Static Deploy:**

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Flush Cache:**

```
 php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with default_head_blocks.xml if the theme type is set to virtual. Check the type field in the theme table. If it's set to 1, try setting it to 0. Then clear the cache and reload the page. See if that does the trick.

See also: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4330